# I lost Central Admin url Sharepoint 2016, Please Help!

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, administration, central-administration, alternate-access-mapping

I have a problem access Central Admin after I edit alternate access mapping.

I used the URL name `"http://name/"` without `:port`, and now it won't open.

When I open using SP 2016 Central admin Application, it goes to "name/" and "Can't reach this page" it said.

Is there a way to edit alternate access mapping again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The central Administration is a web application that has its own alternate access mapping settings.

So you can edit the alternate access for this web application that will not affect other web application AAM settings.

In your case, you can't open central administration to edit these settings now, so you should use Powershell as below

```
Remove-SPAlternateURL -Identity https://InternalURL - Zone 'Zone Type'
```

> **Note:** you should set the Zone type based on the zone that you have provided during configuring AAM like 'Internet' or 'Custom' or 'Intranet' 'Extranet'. Check also [Remove-SPAlternateURL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/remove-spalternateurl?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002973&view=sharepoint-ps) cmdlet, [New-SPAlternateURL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/new-spalternateurl?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002973&view=sharepoint-ps)

---

As I have mentioned in the comments, try to get all AAM URLs for Central Administration URL in all zone using the below command line:

```
Get-SPAlternateURL -WebApplication "CA URL"
```

Based on the result list of the above cmdlet, remove the URL as below

```
 Remove-SPAlternateURL -Identity http://Incoming URL
```

Repeat the above cmdlet for all internal URLs (incoming URL) that you have added to the default zone.

**For example,**

Consider you have added an internal link (incoming URL) "https://test" that should have a `default zone` as shone below

[image]

So you should delete this entry as below

```
Remove-SPAlternateURL -Identity https://test
```

> **Note:**  You cannot delete the default zone for the main URL

Comment: Thanks, it worked.
I already delete url that I don`t need, but still can`t open Central admin.
Can you tell me how to change Public url in Default Zone?
I have 3 Default Url, and 2 of them is have same url.

Comment: @BumiTeknik try to get all alternate access mapping URL using *Get-SPAlternateURL*  then delete what you need with incoming URL like this *Remove-SPAlternateURL -Identity "incoming url"*, Note: at least one default must be there and you can't delete it, so just delete the default entries that you have manually added

Comment: Remove-SPAlternateURL : You must specify the default zone URL for all Web applications. To delete the Alternate URL
Collection, remove the public URLs in all other zones, and then remove the default zone URL.
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-SPAlternateURL -Identity "http://sitename"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...oveAlternateUrl:SPCmdletRemoveAlternateUrl) [Remove-SPAl
   ternateURL], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletRemoveAlternateUrl

Idk what is mean.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118585/discussion-on-answer-by-mohamed-el-qassas-mvp-i-lost-central-admin-url-sharepoin).

Answer (score 0):

**Please follow steps:**

**1.Remove the alternate URL of SharePoint Central Administration.**

```
//Get SharePoint alternate access mappings
Get-SPAlternateURL -WebApplication "http://intranet.crescent.com" | Format-table -AutoSize
//Remove the alternate URL 
Remove-SPAlternateURL -WebApplication https://sitename - Zone 'Zone Type'
```

**2.Add Alternate Access Mapping in SharePoint using PowerShell**

```
New-SPAlternateURL –WebApplication "http://old_sitename" -URL "http://new_sitename" –Zone 'Zone Type'
//For example:New-SPAlternateURL –WebApplication "http://intranet.crescent.com" -URL "http://portal.crescent.com" –Zone Internet
```

**3.Add a binding to the web application in IIS**

[image]